# button "start" ends up in five other buttons one for each letter. tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

so i have been making a countdown timer (with a little bit of copying, but i'm sort of learning Tkinter so ya) so i used a for loop for my buttons and when i did it for "START" it separated it into 5 buttons. one for each letter of START. I don't understand why so please can someone help me.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import time

def iTimer(source, side):
    keepthing = Frame(source, borderwidth=4, bd=4, bg="sky blue")
    keepthing.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return keepthing

def boutonia(source, side, text, command=None):
    keepthing = Button(source, text=text, command=command)
    keepthing.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return keepthing

class app(Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        def funk(self):
           pass

        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.option_add('*Font', 'arial 20 bold')
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('Countdown timer')

        display = StringVar()
        Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN,
            textvariable=display,justify='right',bd=30,bg="sky blue").pack(side=TOP, expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

        for clearBut in(["CE"],["C"]):
            erase = iTimer(self, TOP)
            for ichar in clearBut:
                boutonia(erase, LEFT, ichar, lambda keepthing=display, q=ichar: keepthing.set(''))

        for Numrow in ("789", "456", "123", "0"):
            FunctionNum = iTimer(self, TOP)
            for iEquals in Numrow:
                boutonia(FunctionNum, LEFT, iEquals, lambda keepthing=display, q=iEquals: keepthing.set(keepthing.get() + q))

        # this is where the problem seems to be
        for start in(["START"]):
            count = iTimer(self, TOP)
            for ichar in start:
                boutonia(count, LEFT, ichar, lambda keepthing=display, q=ichar: keepthing.set(''))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies within your nested for-loop. It is iterating for every character in "START" (so it iterates five times).

```
for start in(["START"]):
# This code will execute once.
    for ichar in start:
        # This code will execute five times. Once for each character in "START"
```

Try removing the second for-loop and see if that works.

Comment: it unfortunately did not work. Now the start button doesn't appear on the screen.